# Agregar días y horas a una condición

Tags: javascript, html

**Tengo un dilema.**

Quisiera colocar una condición que se cumpla en algunas horas específicas, pero no he tenido suerte. Por ejmplo, quisiera que el monto ***express*** o servicio de encomienda sea gratis. Entre las 2 y 4 de la tarde de Lunes a Jueves.

Estuve intentando con el día lunes pero no lo logro. Quizá alguien me podría decir qué estoy haciendo mal.

Agradezco la ayuda.

```js
var now = new Date();

var hour = now.getHours();
var day = now.getDay();
var mintues = now.getMinutes();
var MontE1 = 10;
var tipoExpress = "Tu express es de $10";

if (
  day == 1 &&
  hour >= 14 &&
  hour >= 16 &&
  document.getElementById("Exp-1").checked
){
  MontE1 = 0;
  tipoExpress = "Express Gratis";
}
```

Comment: Está condición no refleja lo que quieres lograr: `hour >= 14 && hour >= 16` es verdadera sólo si `hour >= 16` debieras haberla puesto así: `hour >= 14 && hour < 16`

Answer (score 0):

La comparación que haces con la hora es errónea.

```
const now = new Date();

const hour = now.getHours();
const weekDay = now.getDay();
const mintues = now.getMinutes();
const weekDaysFree = [1,2,3,4];

// Valido que: weekDay és lunes, martes, miércoles o jueves. y que hour sea mas grande que 13 y mas pequeño que 16, es decir de 14:00 - 15:59
if (
  weekDaysFree.includes(weekDay) && hour > 13 && hour < 16
){
  console.log('free');
}
```